# Symfony : Wrong path when generating entity on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, symfony5

On Symfony 5 I've got an issue when generating an entity on a subdirectory on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 (don't have this issue on Windows). I use PhpStorm.

For example I generate an entity Event\Category so I do :

```
php bin/console make:entity Event\Category
```

And instead of generating my entity like `src/Event/Category.php` I get this result:

```
src/EventCategory.php
```

Does someone know how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
php bin/console make:entity Event\\Category
```

\ is the bash a special Charater, with -double you escape that